# How do you interpret a DEM?

Tags: raster, dem, gis-principle

I have been asking myself a question for some time. **How do GIS experts interpret a DEM (1) ?**

In my opinion, there are two ways of interpreting the value of a DEM pixel :

1. Consider that the pixel value corresponds to the value of its centroid
2. Consider that the pixel value is a statistical summary of the measurements made within it

I am aware that membership to one of these two categories depends only on the method of construction of the DEM. For example, a TIN interpolation will assign the estimated value of its centroid to the pixel (case 1), while a statistical method (e.g. mean) corresponds to case 2.

But my question is not which method results to which case, but **what is your intuitive interpretation of this kind of data.** For you, does an DEM pixel give a summary of the measurements made within it, or does it only give the value of its centroid?

---

(1) But the question is valid for any type of raster data.

Comment: This Question is of a style mentioned in [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). It is likely to be closed.

Comment: For general discussions or seeking opinions you can use the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis).

Answer (score 3):

A DEM is to my understanding usually created from the interpolation from other data sources, typically point elevations and\or contour lines, the pixel being assigned an elevation value.  When I use a DEM I think of the pixel representing a constant for all parts of the area a pixel represents. I don't think of it as the value for the centroid of the pixel. But that's just me.